# Does NASA need to get permission or pay royalties for music used in space?

Tags: nasa, law

Astronauts have often [brought their own music](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/40645/26446) to entertain themselves, or had music played to them to wake them up.  Some of this music is audible on publicly-available mission recordings.  In addition, [music was included on the Voyager golden record](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/53890/26446).

**Does NASA need to get permission from or pay royalties to the copyright holder when music is used?**

---

Related: [How can I view the Voyager golden record images?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/46816/26446)

Comment: "used in space" ≠ "publicly-available mission recordings" so which are you asking about? Once there is [money in space](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20765/12102) someone in space could charge someone else in space to listen to a recording. We can't assume that [everything happening in space will be televised](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QnJFhuOWgXg).

Comment: @uhoh: The question is about the use *in space*.  However, what NASA does is often open to the public, which complicates the matter.